# Is there a way to integrate google chat into a website?

Tags: api, google-api, google-chat

I am trying to implement the integration of google chat in a website. Is there a rest API for fetching and sending messages that can be connected to our google account? Right now we can fetch chats with Gmail API but that's not reliable because the receiver is not shown in the sent messages.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the google support team and here is their reply:

> here is the information about Google Chat for developers:
> https://developers.google.com/chat There is no option to integrate
> Google Chat into a website.

Hope this thread helps you to find the answer sooner that I did.